# In macOS and using Adobe Illustrator, how can I make a photo appear and look as if the OS was using a different display profile?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-profile, mac, color-management

Say for example in macOS, under System Preferences..Displays..Color.. and choosing the display profile "Rec. ITU-R BT.709-5" as the current display profile (say P_Current).

How can I make a photo using Adobe Illustrator, that appears and looks as if the current profile was "Color LCD" but with the display profile actually set to P_Current ("Rec. ITU-R BT.709-5").

Comment: Is this for demonstration purposes or to fool something? BTW, Rec 709 is a video profile, not really for stills. It's similar to sRGB.

Comment: For demonstration purposes, I just wanted to see if it was possible

Comment: On Mac, if you change your actual display profile, then your Illustrator [or Photoshop] image will change to match. It won't save that way. If your display profile is *correctly* set then in Photoshop [idk if the same exists in Illustrator, I don't use it] You can Colour Proof. View Menu>Custom>Device to emulate>

Comment: @Tetsujin it does. However, turning your os setting means that your monitor nolonger shows correctly.

Comment: @joojaa - of course; yet 'for demonstration' implies it will be switched back moments after the grand *'tadahh!'*

Comment: @Tetsujin yes but the thing is you cant simulate a larger colorspace. Luckily they only differ in gamma

Comment: @joojaa - If the user is on Mac they may well have a p3 screen - we don't know that & this is really an unclear request anyway, possibly even an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I'd like to know *why* we're doing this; to what end. "To demo" is fine... click, hey look what that's like, click back. Done.

Comment: @Tetsuhin. The os will follow whatever you tell it to be its dangerous to tell it something you dont have connected because it will assume it to be true.

Comment: @joojaa - we now seem to be going over the same ground again...

Comment: @Tetsujin no im just pointing out that if you change the os setting then the emulation is limitted by that setting no matter what the monitor can do. So most likely the simulation is close but not exactly what one aims for.